# GET read info for: new users, last edited database, most viewed page, & more

Tags: notion-api

can I use the API to GET read info on several different stats of my Notion workspace?
A few examples of stats I'd like to see:

- Last edited page
- Most viewed page
- Last active user
- New users
- Last edited database
- Last edited item inside a specific database
- Active days any user interacted with a page
- Active days any user visited a page

Cheers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the Notion API [here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/intro) to see what data is directly available and what additional logic you would need around your API calls to track, calculate, and/or determine the data that you are looking for